# C# IReadOnlyDictionary cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm trying to detect body joints using Kinect. I'm struggling to get even the demo code compiled. The code I wrote is as follows:

```
Joint head = body.Joints[JointType.Head];
float x = head.Position.X;
float y = head.Position.Y;
float z = head.Position.Z;
```

I'm getting the body from the body frame detected. The problem is while working with the joint.

The code above gives me the following error:

Error   CS7069  Reference to type 'IReadOnlyDictionary<,>' claims it is defined in 'mscorlib', but it could not be found.

Couldn't find anything concrete over the internet. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the bottom of the MSDN page for `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey,TValue>` there is a [Version Information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh136548(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5) section

> ### Version Information
>
> **Universal Windows Platform**
>   Available since 8
>   **.NET Framework**
>   Available since 4.5
>   **Portable Class Library**
>   Supported in: portable .NET platforms
>   **Windows Phone Silverlight**
>   Available since 8.0
>   **Windows Phone**
>   Available since 8.1

The version your code is running is lower than the minimum supported version for  whatever platform you are building for. Update your codebase to use a newer version of the framework, most likely from the [project properties window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247046.aspx).